# Adding one-shot observer to NSNotificationCenter with [self retain]?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

during the design of a component it turned out that I would need a "one-shot" handler of some notification. I'd have an object that would respond to a notification only once and then it should delete itself. *My object is initialized with autorelease and I can't change this.* Would the following pattern right to achieve this?

```
- (void) init 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:[self retain]
                                             selector:@selector(doRespond)
                                                 name:@"someNotification"
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void) doRespond 
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self 
                                                    name:@"someNotification" 
                                                  object:nil];
    // do something
    [self release];
}
```

Comment: I would negotiate the "close" decision of this question: it might be a useful pattern to handle notifications in this way. At least it worth discussion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That would from first sight be the correct way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, it's nice to have a reinforcement.

Comment: Post back if you encounter any problems! :)